# Bootstrap right Column on top on mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap Page like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       B
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks like:

```
-----
|A|B|
-----
```

So if I look at it on a mobile Device, the Column A is on top, but I want the B on top.
Is this possible?
I tried it with push an pull, but it didn't work.

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 see answer of salmanhijazi

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Use [Column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-column-ordering) to accomplish this.

`col-md-push-6` will "push" the column to the right 6 and `col-md-pull-6` will "pull" the column to the left on "md" or greater view-ports. On any smaller view-ports the columns will be in normal order again.

I think what throws people off, **is that you have to put B above A in your HTML**. There may be a different way to do this where A can go above B in the HTML, but I'm not sure how to do it...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/bpEFe/1/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">A</div>
</div>
```

view-port >= md

```
|A|B|
```

view-port < md

```
|B|
|A|
```

Comment: @JackTheKnife Take a look at the other answer to this question... you push or pull a column by the width of the other column.

Comment: @Schmalzy O yeah - other answer has better explanation. Also found that useful: https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Comment: Having trouble with three column, where the stack order should be center, left, right.

Comment: @AmirDora This is specifically regarding Bootstrap v3. You are likely using v4 in a new asp.net core project, to which this answer does not apply.

Comment: It looks like this approach is obsolete in Bootstrap 4; try column ordering instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251394/bootstrap-v4-push-pull-gone

Answer (score 80):

It's worth noting that if you are using columns that are not both equal to 6, then the push amount will not equal the initial column size.

If you have 2 columns (A & B) and wish for column A to be smaller and to the right on "sm" or greater viewports, but atop a mobile (xs) viewport, you would use the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">B</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, the alignment of the columns will appear off.

Comment: How can i use in this when i have offset set `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"></div><div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"></div>`

Comment: It looks like this approach is obsolete in Bootstrap 4; try column ordering instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251394/bootstrap-v4-push-pull-gone

Answer (score 39):

> [Flexbox Direction](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#direction)

For Bootstrap 4, apply one of the following to your .row div:

```
.flex-row-reverse
```

For responsive settings:

```
.flex-sm-row-reverse
.flex-md-row-reverse
.flex-lg-row-reverse
.flex-xl-row-reverse
```

Comment: any idea how to achieve the same in vuetify ?

Answer (score 21):

In Bootstrap 4, let's say you want to have one order for large screens and a different order for smaller screens:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 order-1 order-lg-2">
      This column will be ordered second on large to extra large screens
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 order-2 order-lg-1">
      This column will be ordered first on large to extra large screens
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can omit `order-1` and `order-2` above. Just added for clarity. Default order will be the order the columns appear in the html.

For more info https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering

Answer (score 12):

The below code work for me

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is now done (in Bootstrap v4) by adding order-# classes.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#grid-system-1

Like this:

```
<div classname='col-md-8 order-2'>...</div>
<div classname='col-md-4 order-1'>...</div>
```

Comment: it will completely change the order even not on mobile view.

Answer (score 5):

I have three bootstrap 4 columns of different sizes.  As the screen gets smaller the third column is hidden, then when the screen gets smaller still and the divs are stacked the order changes so that column 2 is at the top.

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 order-2 order-sm-1">
        <h3>LEFT HAND SECTION</h3>
        <p>For news, links photos or comments.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-5 order-1 order-sm-2">
        <h3>MAIN SECTION</h3>
        <p>The main content for the page.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 d-none d-md-block order-last">
        <h3>BLANK SECTION</h3>
        <p>Will usually just be blank.</p>
    </div>
```

I hope this helps.  I found it difficult to understand this but finally got there with the help of this thread, but it was a bit hit and miss.

Comment: awsome . exact thing, which i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

I used:

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-last">
      <%= render 'form'%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 order-md-first">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 4 includes classes for flex.
See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/utilities-for-layout/

```
<div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       Col 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap V4 (Released January 18, 2018) You can use Reordering Classes.  Info here under Reordering tab.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/