# stacking columns in bootstrap based on screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979062/bootstrap-right-column-on-top-on-mobile-view), but I want several columns stacked in a certain order:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">C</div>
</div>
```

This will display the following:

**mobile screens**

```
B
--
A
--
C
```

**desktop screen**

```
A | B
--|
C |
```

But this is what I want:

**mobile screens**

```
B
--
A
--
C
```

**desktop screen**

```
A | B
  | --
  | C
```

There is a caveat: All columns have different heights, so the stacking needs to be very tight (very little empty space underneath each other). This means I can't put `A` and `B` on their own row since the largest column will push everything down, creating a bunch of empty space in between the stacks.

How can this be done? Ideally a solution would be flexible enough to also allow stacking more columns underneath C or A.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is an offset.

You can set your columns up in that way, using something like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">A</div>
<div class="col-md-6">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">C</div>
</div>
```

The offset pushes it over to be on the second half of your grid, but will stack them appropriately on mobile.

Comment: This won't work because if `A` has a very large height, `C` will be pushed down since it's on its own row. The result will be a huge gap between `B` and `C`.