# Stack horizontal from right to left

Tags: html, css

I am using BootStrap 3 Framework for my portfolio

I am trying to make 2 columns in a section with classes of `col-md-6`. The problem is I want the right hand side column to stack first and not the left hand side when the website goes responsive. So how do I do it?

Comment: Use Push & Pull options available in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Collected from another Answer

Documentation: [grid-column-ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

`col-md-push-6` will "push" the column to the right 6 and col-md-pull-6 will "pull" the column to the left on "md" or greater view-ports. On any smaller view-ports the columns will be in normal order again.

I think what throws people off, is that you have to put B above A in your HTML. There may be a different way to do this where A can go above B in the HTML, but I'm not sure how to do it...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">A</div>
</div>
```

view-port >= md

```
|A|B|
```

view-port < md

```
|B|
|A|
```

Ref: [bootstrap-right-column-on-top-on-mobile-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979062/bootstrap-right-column-on-top-on-mobile-view)

Comment: Thanks Alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use `col-xs-6` too for extra small devices.

Comment: @EugeneS This should not be a comment as per SE guidelines.