# CSS- Getting 100% width div to wrap under another [jsfiddle]

Tags: css

In a responsive layout, I have two columns. The left column is the sidebar and the right column is the content.

Using a media query, when the screen width is tiny, the columns turn to 100% width and stack on top of each other.

In this case, I want the sidebar (the first div) to appear beneath the content (the second div).

I tried using `float: right` on a small screen once it's at 100%, but at 100% width, the float apparently doesn't matter.

```
.left, .right {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
.left {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
.space {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}
```

And on the page:

```
<div class="left half"> <!-- To mimic full screen size -->
Left
</div>
<div class="right half">
Right
</div>

<div class="space"></div>

<div class="left"> <!-- To mimic small screen size -->
Left
</div>
<div class="right"><!-- This should appear first -->
Right
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ph09frvw/

I'm sure this is not the first time someone wanted to wrap the sidebar under the content, I just haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: samething done in Bootstrap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979062/bootstrap-right-column-on-top-on-mobile-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` and use the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to change the order of the `<div>` elements. While floating can be helpful for horizontal alignment, it will be of little help for vertical alignment, Here is an example:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.left {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  background: green;
}
.full {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.full > .left,
.full > .right {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex full">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `display:flex;` property combined with `flex-direction` to reorder your divs. Ref: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

Comment: add a jsfiddle to clarify your answer

Answer (score 0):

Remember to reference your related class-names in your HTML elements' class attribute.

Your CSS `display:block` should do the trick, else try something like:
`float: left`

When you use: `display:block` on a `div` element, you do not need to specify `width:100%` as it should automatically span across the width if it is not hindered by anything else.

Make sure the `position` of these elements are "relative", else it may not work as expected; it may be stated globally that some specific tags should be displayed "absolute" and that may break what you're trying to achieve.