# Overlay column 1 on column 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a mobile view where the first column of the row goes on top of the second column.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><div class="loginpart"><img id ="icon" src="../images/athletics-logo.png"/><h2>Athletes Profiling </h2>
            <input type="button" class="login" name="login" value="Log In"/></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style="padding: 0"><img id ="header"/><div class="mantra"><h2>Go Wolves!</h2></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the thing is, I want the `loginpart` class to go on top of the `col-md-8` when on mobile. I tried searching for answers but ended with nothing. I don't want it to stack on top of each other.

```
A | B = A goes on top of B
```

If the implementation or my understanding is faulty, please do educate me. Thanks!

Edit: I tried the push-pull bootstrap function, but all it does is put the second column under the first column (which isn't what I was hoping for), but instead overlap both columns when switched to mobile view, not stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap right Column on top on mobile view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979062/bootstrap-right-column-on-top-on-mobile-view)

Comment: @XYZ edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try position absolute with push. You can use Z-index to get the correct column on top.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
            <div class="loginpart">
                <img id ="icon" src="" />
                <h2 style="color: grey;">Athletes Profiling </h2>
                <input type="button" class="login" name="login" value="Log In"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
            <img id="header" src="" />
            <div class="mantra">
                <h2 style="color: blue;">Go Wolves!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!