# bootstrap v4 push pull gone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Looking at bootstrap v4 updates:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system-1

> ...Dropped push and pull modifier classes for the new flexbox-powered order classes. For example, instead of .col-8.push-4 and .col-4.pull-8, you’d use .col-8.order-2 and .col-4.order-1.

But when I use the order function it doesn't seem to work the same as the push pull method. It stacks the rows up just like the first row in the code below.

My goal is to have a img on the left with text on the right on one row then text on the left and a img on the right on the next row on a desktop.  When its resized in a smaller screen I would like each image stacked on top of the text it corresponds with.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!--img-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!--text-->
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 order-2">
                <!--text-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 order-1">
                <!--img-->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `push` and `pull` the new bootstrap-4 beta v2 uses `order` instead.

From github/bootstrap,


"Updated the grid to drop push, pull, and offset in favor of new .order- modifiers and margin utilities."

read more on [changelog](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to change order for example on `md` you can define first normal order for that size and then `order-n` for all smaller sizes. So your code should look like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      img
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 order-2 order-md-1">
      text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-1 order-md-2">
      img
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works very well in mobile and desktop. Thank you!