# Second column on top on mobile Liquid

Tags: grid, responsive, liquid

On large screens I want to have |A| |B|, on mobile I want
|**B**|
|A|
I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20979197/4509634) that this is possible via Bootstrap. However I use shopify's liquid. I saw in the theme.scss that there are -push classes - tried the following

```
<div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half section-header__item">
  <h1 class="section-header__title">
    {{ collection.title }}
  </h1>
    <div class="section-header__subtext rte">
      {{ collection.description }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section-header text-center medium-up--push-one-quarter">

    <img src="{{collection.image  | img_url: '235x235' }}">

</div>
```

However having the `medium-up--push-one-quarter` doesn't seem to make any difference (I am new to these css grid magic). I didn't see anything about `pull` in the theme.scss (which is used in the bootstrap solution from the link above).
Is what I want achievable and if yes, how?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep current markup and on mobile just change order of blocks using flexbox and rule `order:1;` for block B, don't forget `display: flex;` for the container of this 2 blocks